# Hide add to cart button when quantity max value is 0 (Shopify)

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

I am trying out Shopify and BookThatApp to hire products online.

The app forces the quantity field to have a max value of 0 when it is booked out, meaning you can't proceed to purchase. For usability I would like to grey out the add to cart button when this is the case.

See for yourself selecting May 13 then 3 days:

http://propeller-6.myshopify.com/products/007-never-say-never-again-sign

I was thinking, and tried, something along these lines:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( "#product-select-option-0" ).change(function() {
      var maxquantity = $('#quantity').attr('max');
      if  (maxquantity = 0) {
         // hide button
      }
    });
});
```

Am I close? :)

Thanks
Caroline

Comment: Don't really understand what you want... But if you really have access to the max quantity using javascript, you can simply disabled the button: `$('#mybutton').attr('disabled', true)`. And be carefull, you should use a `==` in your `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks Holt. Disabling the button is not the issue, it is that I am not sure if I can get the max value each time the dropdown is updated. I basically want to hide the button when the input max value is 0.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for heads up about the `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the main issue was with the `change` function. I got it working like this:

```
$(document).on("change",'#product-select-option-0', function() { 
  var productquantity = $('#quantity').attr('value');
    if  (productquantity == 0) {
        $('#add-to-cart').prop('disabled', true);
      }
})
```

Also changed `=` to `==` and `.attr('max');` to `.attr('value');` (as max is only supported in Internet Explorer 10, Opera, Chrome, and Safari).

Comment: Good job, though you might still want to consider using `<=` instead of `==` as I suggested and explained in my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't work because you aren't using a right Javascript condition.

`if  (maxquantity = 0) {` is not correct Javascript, you probably would want to change the condition to either `<=` which means: less or equal to 0 or `==` which means: equal to 0.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( "#product-select-option-0" ).change(function() {
      var maxquantity = $('#quantity').attr('max');
      if  (maxquantity <= 0) {
         // hide button
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Daan, but I realised my issue was mostly with the `.change` function not working. I took your advice though and used `==` :)